# Achar item no array

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se meu código está certo. pois gostaria de pegar o nome vinculado com que está vinculado com o código(id), onde mmot recebe um numero para ser procurado dentro do array. Obrigado

```
    $url = file_get_contents('https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/motos/marcas');

    function get_page($url){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;

        foreach ($result as $key) {
            if($key['codigo'] == $mmot){
                $mmot = $key['$mmot']['nome']; 
            }
        }

    }

    $marcafinal = $mmot;
```

Comment: se você der o return no $result ele encerrara a função ai sem executar o foreach

Comment: Oi, tentei fazer o que vc falou e tirei o return, mas continua me retornando nenhum valor :(

Comment: postei um exemplo que teste, caso queira testar ai, testei e ta ok

Answer (score 1):

Essa forma da certo e nem precisa usar o curl, caso precise só editar da forma que achar melhor, exemplo funcionando:

```
 <?php
$url = file_get_contents('https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/motos/marcas');
$mmot = "60";

function get_page($url,$mmot){
    $result = json_decode($url,true);

    foreach($result as $key)
    {
        if($key['codigo'] == $mmot)
        {
            return $key['nome'];
        }
    }

}

$marcafinal = get_page($url,$mmot);

echo "Valor: ".$marcafinal;  

?>
```

Comment: Oi usei o seu exemplo e me voltou esse erro aqui
Warning: file_get_contents(https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/70/modelos/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_page() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\plus\inserir.php:59) in

Comment: é que esse link (https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/70/modelos/) não existe no site, ele não retorna nada só um erro 404 que não foi encontrado nada, já esse link (https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/motos/marcas) ele retorna um json certinho, tente ver se não mudaram o link da api

Comment: ta, obrigado. :)

Comment: dei uma olhada na api e vi que o codigo 70 não existe, se você testar esse link (https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas) consegue ver todas as marcas,  e se usar dessa forma (https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos) onde o 59 é um código válido, ele aparecerá os modelos desse código

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está cheio de problemas, mas vou tentar mostrar um por um aqui. Entendi que está fazendo uma chamada pelo `curl` e que quer manipular a resposta, então vamos lá:

```
// $url está sendo declarado fora do escopo de onde será usado, no caso, o seu método
$url = file_get_contents('https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/motos/marcas');

// essa função não foi chamada em lugar nenhum
function get_page($url){ // $url é redeclarado como alterador de parametro e ofusca a variável ali em cima

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // está retornando o corpo da response, o bloco for ali em baixo não será executado
    return $result;

    // você sabe o que está vindo no $result para enumerar ele?
    foreach ($result as $key) {

        // quem é codigo e quem é $mmot (que nem foi declarado)?
        if($key['codigo'] == $mmot){

            // aqui nunca será processado, pois será atirado um erro na linha acima.
            // mas se $mmot fosse declarado, a linha abaixo também não faria lógica, já que está procurando a chave '$mmot' na coleção $key.
            $mmot = $key['$mmot']['nome']; 
        }
    }

}

$marcafinal = $mmot;
```

Sua pergunta não está clara e a refatoração do seu código seria aproximadamente isso:

```
$url_endpoint = file_get_contents('https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/motos/marcas');

function get_page($url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $responseValues = json_decode($result, true); // isso se sua API for JSON

    // Você precisa associar esse $mmot a algo, não pode deixar ele vago e sem declaração.
    $mmot = 0;
    $returnValue = null;

    foreach ($result as $key) {
        if($key['codigo'] == $mmot){
            $returnValue = $key['nome']; 
        }
    }

    return $returnValue;
}

$marcafinal = get_page($url_endpoint);
```

Fiz isso levando em consideração que `$mmot` é um código que leva até o objeto JSON que procura por `nome`. Assim, você deverá especificar `$mmot` no método onde deixei claro ali, ou passar como um parâmetro.

Answer (score -2):

Ta errado, você está declarando o $mmot dentro do if e usando ele na condição, acredito que você tenha que declarar ela antes

Comment: o $mmot ta declarado antes sim, eu declarei ele antes de fazer a função.

Comment: @VictorAugusto Então talvez esteja faltando você passar ele como parâmetro da função *(como foi mostrado em outras respostas aqui)* ou colocar dentro da função uma indicação que `$mmot` é global  => `global $mmot;`, OBS. Vale a pena você editar sua pergunta para colocar a informação que você colocou neste comentário.

Answer (score -2):

Código testado e funcionando:

```
<?php

function get_page($url){

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function procuraMmot($mmot) {
    $retorno = '';
    $url = 'https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/motos/marcas';
    $resultado = json_decode(get_page($url), true);

    foreach ($resultado as $value) {
        if($value['codigo'] == $mmot){
            $retorno = $value['nome']; 
        }
    }
    return $retorno;
}

$resultado = procuraMmot(60);
echo "resultado: $resultado";
```